# How to debug why Flutter is unable to load an asset

Tags: arp, nt

[DebugConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg7hj.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_json_http/local_json.dart';


void main() {
   runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Http Json'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.green),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const LocalJson()));
                },
                child: const Text('Local Json')),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```